# How to solve uri 1015 question of Distance between two points?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve Bee (uri) problem #1015: [Distance Between Two Points](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/repository/UOJ_1015_en.html):

> Read the four values corresponding to the x and y axes of two points in the plane, <sub><sub>1</sub></sub> (<sub><sub>1</sub></sub>, <sub><sub>1</sub></sub>) and <sub><sub>2</sub></sub> (<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>, <sub><sub>2</sub></sub>) and calculate the distance between them, showing four decimal places after the comma, according to the formula:
>
> Distance = √[ ( <sub><sub>2</sub></sub>− <sub><sub>1</sub></sub> )² + ( <sub><sub>2</sub></sub>− <sub><sub>1</sub></sub> )² ]
>
> #### Input
>
> The input file contains two lines of data. The first one contains two double values: **<sub><sub>1</sub></sub> <sub><sub>1</sub></sub>** and the second one also contains two double values with one digit after the decimal point: **<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> <sub><sub>2</sub></sub>**.
>
> #### Output
>
> Calculate and print the distance value using the provided formula, with 4 digits after the decimal point.
>
> | Input Sample | Output Sample |
> | --- | --- |
> | `1.0 7.0` `5.0 9.0` | `4.4721` |
> | `-2.5 0.4` `12.1 7.3` | `16.1484` |
> | `2.5 -0.4` `-12.2 7.0` | `16.4575` |

Below is the JavaScript code I wrote. But it says 85% of the test cases fail, although the output comes out correct.

```js
let x1 = 1.0;
let y1 = 7.0;
let x2 = 5.0;
let y2 = 9.0;

function Distance(a, b, c, d) {
  let z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a - b, 2) + Math.pow(c - d, 2));
  console.log(z.toFixed(4));
}

Distance(x2, x1, y2, y1);
```

Comment: `The input file contains two lines of data`. Where do you read and parse the file?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to set hard coded values for your variables, but to read the input. The judge has a [help page](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/faqs/about/examples) indicating how you could read the input using JavaScript:

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
```

Then, depending on the input format, you should extract the data in the structure you need. For this particular problem you could do:

```
const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = input.split(/\s+/g).map(Number);
```

With that, your code will work:

```
const input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = input.split(/\s+/g).map(Number);

function Distance(a, b, c, d) {
  let z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a - b, 2) + Math.pow(c - d, 2));
  console.log(z.toFixed(4));
}

Distance(x2, x1, y2, y1);
```

### Remarks

It is not really necessary to create a function here, but if you do, it is better practice to not have the `console.log` inside of it. Instead, have the function *return* the distance. That way it is not tied to I/O specifics. Have the main code format the output with 4 decimals and output it.

Secondly, it is common practice in the JavaScript community to reserve PascalCase for names of constructors/classes, and use camelCase elsewhere, so name your function `distance` instead of `Distance`.

I would also use the exponentiation (`**`) operator, which leads to shorter code:

```
const distance = (a, b, c, d) => ((a - b) ** 2 + (c - d) ** 2) ** 0.5;

const input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = input.split(/\s+/g).map(Number);
const result = distance(x2, x1, y2, y1);
console.log(result.toFixed(4));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the file read or at least the line parsing

```js
let file = `1.0 7.0
5.0 9.0`;

function Distance(a, b, c, d) {
  let z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a - b, 2) + Math.pow(c - d, 2));
  console.log(z.toFixed(4));
}

const [_, x1, y1, x2, y2] = file.match(/(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)/);

Distance(x2, x1, y2, y1);
```

Answer (score -4):

The problem you're encountering might be related to the precision of the floating-point arithmetic in JavaScript. Floating-point numbers can sometimes have small rounding errors that could lead to slight discrepancies when compared to the expected output. To improve the accuracy of your solution, you can use the Number.EPSILON constant to compare the calculated distance with the expected result.

Here's the modified code with the suggested improvement:

```js
let x1 = 1.0;
let y1 = 7.0;
let x2 = 5.0;
let y2 = 9.0;

function Distance(a, b, c, d) {
    let z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a - b, 2) + Math.pow(c - d, 2));
    return z;
}

let calculatedDistance = Distance(x2, x1, y2, y1);
let expectedDistance = 5.0; // Modify this to match the expected result

if (Math.abs(calculatedDistance - expectedDistance) < Number.EPSILON) {
    console.log("Distance calculation is correct!");
} else {
    console.log("Distance calculation is incorrect.");
    console.log("Calculated Distance:", calculatedDistance.toFixed(4));
    console.log("Expected Distance:", expectedDistance);
}
```

In this code, we calculate the distance using the Distance function and then compare the calculated distance with the expected result using the Math.abs function and the Number.EPSILON constant. This approach takes into account potential small rounding errors and provides a more accurate way to check the correctness of your solution.

Comment: It should be noted that `Number.EPSILON` is only useful for small numbers. For higher-magnitude values, it won't work because imprecision is relative to the magnitude of the numbers involved. Usually, an application decides on its own accuracy threshold according to the details of the problem domain.

Comment: This is chatGPT, which is banned at SO

Comment: Also the result is identical to OP's result which is deemed correct. So it is the methods used or the order of things that the specific test is not accepting